# How to fetch JSON data from HTML DIV on same page for Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, highcharts

I am trying to render a Highchart which uses JSON data as its source. However instead of storing it in a different file or webpage, it gets created (from MYSQL queries) in a HTML division on the same page. What changes can I make to the following code so that it will read the JSON data from the required div (let us call it `JSONContainer`):

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

I tried `getElementByID('JSONContainer')`in place of `'data.json'` but I guess that is not the correct way to do it. What can I do?

EDIT:
This is my code:

```
$.getJSON("getElementById(JSONContainer)", function(json) {
    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; //rendering X Axis
    $.each(json, function( index, value ) {
             options.series[index-1] = value;  //Making sure we skip first as that is X Axis
    }); 
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: what you are getting as `data`?

Comment: `data.json` in this piece of code is a json file where data is stored.

Comment: not that.. what you get as response when you do `$.getJSON`?

Comment: I get data is JSON format ie. Key: Value which is used as source for my chart

Comment: paste your json output

Comment: I cant, its confidential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to make `$.getJSON` to get the data which is already on the html div.

if your data is something like this below

```
<div id="JSONContainer">[{"name":"LOG_DATE","data":["2015-09-08","2015-09-09"]},{"name":"a","data":[30.5‌​,87.5]},{"name":"b","data":[55.5,82.4]},{"name":"c","data":[82,57.46]},{"name":"d‌​","data":[82.4,87.4]}]</div>
```

Just do this

```
var json = JSON.parse($('#JSONContainer').text());

options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; //rendering X Axis
$.each(json, function( index, value ) {
    options.series[index-1] = value;  //Making sure we skip first as that is X Axis
}); 
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

PS:The `"` around the keys and values are important as JSON parse needs that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: A slight complication in my code is that I am also rendering X-Axis from JSON. Do you want me to post that portion of the code so that you can check it?

Comment: not required.. you can keep the parsed json in to a separate variable and get the X-Axis out of it and set it on to chart. if you want me to check it i can :)

Comment: Can you add a general structure of your json data too? I need the keys and how the json is formatted like array and objects. you can withhold the values..

Comment: [{"name":"LOG_DATE","data":["2015-09-08","2015-09-09"]},{"name":"a","data":[30.5,87.5]},{"name":"b","data":[55.5,82.4]},{"name":"c","data":[82,57.46]},{"name":"d","data":[82.4,87.4]}]

Comment: Yes, so it should work for you.. I have updated the js code for you in the answer.